# Is it possible to choose between two different SELECT statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, count, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that joins many different tables and returns 1 row. I'm not too sure about the workings of this procedure but I don't believe that is too important here.

The problem I have is that depending on a number of different things, it is possible that this procedure can on occasion return en empty row (no result) and if this happens, we can simply make a couple of changes within the procedure to force it to point to some another table and all is good. The thing is I would like to do this automatically and while I know it will be possible to do it at the application end (by having two separate stored procedures and by call one and if there is no result, call the other) but I would rather avoid this, so:

Is it possible within MySQL to call one SELECT statement and based on the result, either return that result or call a slightly different SELECT statement, ideally within the one stored procedure?

something like

```
IF (SELECT something FROM somewhere) = '1 row'
THEN 
     # 1 row returned so all good.
     SELECT something FROM somewhere
ELSE
     # 0 rows returned so do this one instead.
     SELECT somethingElse FROM somewhereElse
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: .See COALESCE()

Comment: Show your stored procedure

Comment: @Strawberry I had thought about this but doesn't that require only 1 column to be returned by the SELECT statement? 

So for example, the below would not work;

SELECT COALESCE (
        (SELECT * FROM `faults` WHERE `fault_id` = 2 ), (SELECT * FROM `faults` WHERE `fault_id` = 131 )
    );
as each SELECT statement returns more than one column.

In my above made up example, fault_id 2 does not exist.

Comment: *I have a stored procedure that joins many different tables and returns 1 row.* Does this means "1 row or 0 rows" or "1 row or not 1 (0, 2, 3, ...) rows"? If first - does your SP output query contains explicit `LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is what procedures allow for you to do (=add logic). You can for example use temp tables for this:

```
drop temporary table if exists result_tmp;

create temporary table result_tmp
select something from somewhere;

if (row_count()>0) then
  select * from result_tmp;
else
  select somethingelse from somewhereelse;
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single `select` statement with `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select something from somewhere
union all
select somethingElse from somewhereElse where not exists (select something from somewhere)
```

The `not exists` condition prevents the second member of the `union all` to return something if the first member produced at least one row.

Comment: This looked interesting, I had been flirting with UNION myself, ordering and then limiting the result.

How would this work if both of my SELECTS had their own WHERE though?

Take the following as very basic examples?

'SELECT * FROM `faults` WHERE `fault_id` =50 # this doesn't exist.
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `faults` WHERE `fault_id` =131 # this does exist, so
**WHERE** NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `faults` WHERE `fault_id` =50)'

Comment: it doesn't seem to like the **WHERE** part of the **WHERE NOT EXISTS** I'm assuming because I already have a **WHERE** in the 2nd **SELECT** statement.

Comment: I've eventually simplified with a **SELECT** blah, blah, **UNION SELECT** blah, blah **LIMIT 1**. A much simplified solution which I've yet to check as part of the huge procedure but in principle, it looks as though it will work, in that it will limit the result to 1 row and use it. Thanks for the pointers meantime ;)

Comment: @plisken: is this what you want? `SELECT * FROM faults WHERE fault_id =50 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM faults WHERE fault_id =131 AND WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM faults WHERE fault_id =50)` Note that if both members of `union all` relate to the same table, then there are better solutions that `union all` (in your question, you had `from somewhere` and `from somewereElese`, so it looked like two different tables).